# Сделать разницу между основным сайтом и Метой более очевидной

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Вот два вопроса:

[Приложение под Android для передачи по Bluetooth](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-bluetooth)

[Как дать имя подвыражению в регулярных выражениях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

Заданы на Мете, хотя им явно место на основном сайте. Оба заданы пользователями, у которых есть профили с несколькими вопросами на основном сайте. Я предполагаю, что они просто прерпутали сайты из-за их внешнего сходства. Возможно, стоит поменять цветовую гамму Меты, чтобы различия сильнее бросались в глаза.

Comment: А может просто сразу в комментарии подсказать людям где надо размещать такие вопросы?    (а на мете, конечно же, не отвечать) (**сделают тут когда-нибудь \n в комметрариях?**)

Comment: @avp, \n ставится стандартной комбинацией: Shift+Enter, правда толку от этого мало, да, это верно

Comment: Думаю, сделано специально, чтобы не увлекались в комментариях.

Comment: Попробую...  Shift-Enter

Спасибо, @mega!

(все равно не работает)

Answer (score 7):

Народ просто ещё не разобрался, что и как на Stack Overflow. Даже если вы раскрасите Мету в ярко-красный цвет, а основной сайт — в ярко-зелёный, то это ничего не скажет о том, где надо задавать вопрос по программированию, а где — обсуждать сайт.

Посмотреть в левый верхний угол и проверить наличие надписи "meta" (а также цвет логотипа) — не так уж сложно. Это вопрос привычки, не более.

Кроме того, дизайн общий для всех бета-сайтов, поэтому лучше задать вопрос на Meta.SE, а не здесь.

Comment: Если человек не может разобраться в **русскоязычном** сайте, где каждая кнопочка подписана, то ему не нужно пользоваться этим сайтом.

Comment: Думаю, дело в двух вещах: 1) никто не читает справку, 2) слово «мета» не говорит новичкам ни о чём (усугубляется пунктом 1).

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что нужно запрещать задавать вопросы со специфичными только основному сайту тэгами, например java, C# и т.д.
Что-то не могу придумать вопрос для меты с тэгом sql

Comment: Ну, на собственно Мете можно спросить, как устроена база данных самого StackExchange. Да и только )

Answer (score 2):

Вариант - запрещать вопросы на Мете до тех пор пока человек не сделал чего-нибудь из следующего.

1. Задал вопрос на не-мете, набравший 1 и более рейтинга и принял ответ к нему.
2. Заработал хотя бы N репутации на ответах. (N не менее 50)

Это гарантирует, что пользователь уже в курсе, где находятся нормальные вопросы и ответы.

Да, я понимаю, что это жесткая мера, и что En.SO как-то обходится без этого. (Как-как, да просто сразу минусуют и покрывают флагами как ежа иголками).

Comment: Вообще-то, порог уже есть: 5 репы. И выше его поднимать будет слишком сурово, потому что проблемы возникают чаще при первом вопросе, а не десятом.

Comment: @Discord по проблемам, возникающим при первом вопросе, написан десяток статей. [ask], [answer] и другие.